# Evaluating $\int \frac{1}{2+3 \sin\left(x\right)}$

Tags: calculus

I'm helping my daughter on her calculus homework and it has been many years for me. The problem is
$$
\int \frac{1}{2+3 \sin\left(x\right)} dx
$$
From WolframAlpha, the substitution should be $u = \tan\frac{x}{2}$. Once you have the substitution, the solution is quite straightforward.

My question is how on earth do you come up with that substitution? Are there any rubrics/recipes? Or is it just intuition?

Comment: The [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution) is a common trick to evaluate trigonometric integrals. It is not something you (or your daughter) are supposed to some up with yourself; you are supposed to recognise the trigonometric form, know that such a substition might work, and try to see if it does. That said, there may of course be other (and better/easier) solutions in some cases.

Comment: Adding to what Myself just wrote, the Wikipedia article notes that " Michael Spivak wrote that "The world's sneakiest substitution is undoubtedly" this technique"

Answer (score 4):

[Weierstrass Substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula#The_Weierstrass_substitution), $z=\tan(x/2)$, works well in this kind of integral:
$$
\begin{align}
\sin(x)&=\frac{2z}{1+z^2}\\[6pt]
\cos(x)&=\frac{1-z^2}{1+z^2}\\[6pt]
\mathrm{d}x&=\frac{2\mathrm{d}z}{1+z^2}
\end{align}
$$
Then
$$
\begin{align}
\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{2+3\sin(x)}
&=\int\frac1{2+3\frac{2z}{1+z^2}}\frac{2\mathrm{d}z}{1+z^2}\\
&=\int\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z^2+3z+1}\\
&=\int\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{(z+3/2)^2-5/4}\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt5}\int\left(\frac1{z+3/2-\sqrt{5/4}}-\frac1{z+3/2+\sqrt{5/4}}\right)\,\mathrm{d}z
\end{align}
$$
which is a simple form (thanks to Michael Hardy for pointing out partial fractions). Then back-substitute to get the answer in terms of $x$.

Comment: Instead of that last trigonometric substitution, you could just use partial fractions after you've got an integral of a rational function.

Comment: Doh! I will fix that. Thanks!

Comment: It's also been questioned on mathoverflow recently whether the "Weierstrass solution" should be called that.  Fred Rickey has said he's searched through Weierstrass' publications without finding it.  Stewart's _Calculus_ calls it that, IIRC.  So did Stewart introduce the usage, or is it older?

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I don't know the history. I just go by what Wikipedia calls it. I'd be interested to know if it has a better name since I use it a lot.

Comment: I can't go by what Wikipedia calls it, since I am the initial creator of that Wikipedia article (and hundreds of others), and I just went by what some book called it.  I think it might have been Stewart.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: before I saw the article on Wikipedia, I used to call it the "half tangent" or "tangent half angle" substitution. I see that [on Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Calculus/Integration_techniques/Tangent_Half_Angle), they call it the tangent half angle substitution, even in the [September 2008 revision](http://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=Calculus/Integration_techniques/Tangent_Half_Angle&oldid=1281712).

Comment: The origin of the substitution is the rational parametrization of the unit circle (which surely must predate Weierstrass). Consider the line with slope $u$ through $(-1,0)$. Its other intersection with the unit circle is at $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$, and so $u=\tan(\theta/2)$.

Comment: Correction: It was [here on m.s.e.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/420364) that this was questioned.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I hope you don't mind me adding the link to your comment.

Comment: It was one of my posted questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420364/who-is-buried-in-weierstrass-tomb